# Calculating phase only component of a signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft

I am working in the field of digital signal processing. Recently I read a paper that tells about phase only component of a Signal.
It is given that the phase only component is calculated as **$r_{phase}=\frac{F(n)}{||F(n)||}$**, where $F(n)$ is discrete Fourier transform of any signal $n$ and $||F(n)||$ is Fourier magnitude of signal $n$. I know that $F(n)$ can be calculated as `F(n)=dft2(n)`, Can anyone please tell that how to calculate the $||F(n)||$ in MATLAB.

Comment: its difficult for me, hopefully NOT for others.

Comment: Can I please ask what does `dft2` means here?

Comment: @A_A, dft2 means discrete Fourier transform for 2D signal.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean fft2 in MATLAB notation (its the same calculation as 2-D DFT, but with less computation time.

Then, you can go for:

```
F = fft2(I);
r = F ./ abs(F)
```

to get the phase-only information of the Fourier Transform.